# I think $A,B$ must be closed and disjoint

Tags: general-topology

Prove that in every metric space, $(X; d)$, is possible find a continous function$f\colon X\to \mathbb{R}$ such, if  $ A $ and $ B $ are two subsets of $ X $ then $ f(x) = 1 $, for every $ x\in A $ and $ f(x) = 0 $ , for every $ x \in B $.

$\textbf{Proof}$:
Let be $A,B\subset X$ non empty and $ a\in A $ y $ b\in B $, consider the function : $f\colon X\to\mathbb{R}^+$ defined by:
$$f(x)=\dfrac{d(x,B)}{d(x,B)+d(x,A)}$$

For $a\in A$: 
$$f(a)=\dfrac{d(a,B)}{d(a,B)+d(a,A)}=\dfrac{d(a,B)}{d(a,B)+0}=1$$

For $b\in B$:
$$f(b)=\dfrac{d(b,B)}{d(b,B)+d(b,A)}=\dfrac{0}{0+d(b,A)}=0$$

So, $f$ holds: 
$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{lcr} 1,\textrm{ if } x \in A \\ 0, \textrm{ if } x\in B\end{array} \right.$$

The question is: What happens if $A\cap B\neq\emptyset?$ Don't I need a condition for $A,B$ to be disjoint? What happens in the clousure of both sets?

I think It should say: Let be $A,B\subset X$ two non-empty, disjoint and closed susbets. Or am I taking the wrong function? How to prove continuity

Comment: Yes, $A$ and $B$ should be closed, disjoint, and non-empty. For continuity, prove that the functions $f_A(x)=d(x,A)$ and $f_B(x)=d(x,B)$ are continuous; then $f$ is the quotient of two continuous functions, and the denominator is never $0$.

Comment: Hey thanks. I needed this second point of view. You can write this as an answer for select it as correct answer?

Comment: Done! You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $A$ and $B$ should be closed, disjoint, and non-empty. For continuity, prove that the functions $f_A(x)=d(x,A)$ and $f_B(x)=d(x,B)$ are continuous; then $f$ is the quotient of two continuous real-valued functions, and the function in the denominator is never $0$. (That’s one reason why you need $A$ and $B$ to be disjoint.)